# Rational And Real Numbers Density

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are dense and that there cardinalities are $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph$ corresponding.

Does from these facts I can assume that any interval of $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, let say $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ has infinite elements?

Comment: You need to work on the English, as it stands this is not comprehensible.

Comment: if you're saying what I think you're saying, what about $\{1,2\}$?

Comment: Sorry @GregoryGrant I meant interval and not a set (edited)

Comment: @IttayWeiss I meant an interval, sorry

Comment: then yes, if an interval has more than one element, then it has infinitely many.